# Why is the remove menu mobile not working?

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');

navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(){
    navMenu.classList.toggle('show');
})

/*===== REMOVE MENU MOBILE =====*/


const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

navLink.forEach(function (linkClick) {
linkClick.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const removeMenu = e.currentTarget.classList;
   if(removeMenu.classList.contains('show')){
       removeMenu.classList.remove('show');
   }
})




})
```

the remove menu mobile is not working, what is the problem?
it stopped working when I did queryselectorAll and added forEach,
please help me out with that forEach

Answer (score 0):

Check the JavaScript console log.  What's probably happening is that the script is "dying silently" due to some error.  JavaScript *usually* produces no console output at all when an error happens – it just stops running!  *(Don't ask me why.)*

Answer (score 0):

This code did the work for me

```
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
 
function linkAction () {
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');
navMenu.classList.remove('show');
}

navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction))
```